# best way to detect the trigonometric identites that shall work on a given expression so as to simplify it accordingly?

Tags: trigonometry

how to tell that what trigonometric identity (a.k.a. Pythagorean trigonometric identity) will work on the given equation , so then you can simplify the equation accordingly in order to apply that identity?

I'm talking about applying these if you still dont know what i'm saying  :

$\sin^2A + \cos^2 A = 1,$

$\tan^2 A + 1 = \sec^2 A,$

$\cot^2 A + 1= \csc^2 A$

Examples would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  All 3 equations use different trigonometric functions, yet they are all basically the same identity.  Take the first and divide by $\cos^2A$ to get the second or $\sin^2A$ to get the third.

Comment: The way to tell what will work is by trying things to see what works. Do enough of that, and you will develop a sense of what works. In other words, the way to do this is for *you* to do examples, not for others to do examples for you.